# Integral $\int_0^{\pi/2} x\cot(x)dx$, Differentiation w.r.t. parameter only.

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, contest-math

Integrate using differentiation w.r.t. parameter only: $\int_0^{\pi/2} x\cot(x)dx$.
We can express this as $\int_0^{\pi/2} x\cdot\frac{\cos(x)}{\sin(x)}dx$.

We can substitute $u=\sin(x)$ to start but I am not sure if that will do us any good.

If we use $x_i$ as a parameter, the answer is of the form. $\lim_{x_i \to 1}I(xi)=\lim_{x_i \to 1}\frac{\pi}{2}\ln(\xi+1)$.

NOTE: Only use differentiation with respect to parameters.

Comment: What is differentiation w.r.t. parameter? In any case, $\int x \cot x dx = x\int \cot x dx - \int (\dfrac{dx}{dx}(\int \cot x dx)) = x (\ln(\sin x)) - \int \ln(\sin x) dx + c$. The second integral with limits $0$ to $\pi/2$ is $-\ln 2 \dfrac{\pi}{2}$ and take limit as $x \to 0$ in first integral.

Comment: Where does appear the parameter you want to differentiate with respect to ?  Where does appear $\xi$ ? Please clarify.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici The point of the problem is to find a function you can introduce a parameter to.  Thus I don't know where $\xi$ appears, that is the point of the problem lol

Comment: @JeffFaraci You likely mean the [“Leibniz integral rule”](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule).

Answer (score 5):

found the way to go...We can want to solve

$$
I=\int_0^{\pi/2}x\cot(x) dx,
$$
so we introduce a parameter $\xi$ by writing

$$
I(\xi)=\int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{\tan^{-1}(\xi\tan(x))}{\tan(x)} dx
$$
and in the limit $\xi \to 1$ we recover I.  Taking a derivative we obtain
$$
I'(\xi)=\frac{d}{d\xi}\int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{\tan^{-1}(\xi\tan(x))}{\tan(x)} dx=\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{\partial}{\partial \xi} \bigg(\frac{\tan^{-1}(\xi\tan(x))}{\tan(x)} \bigg)dx
$$
Now we take the derivative to obtain
$$
I'(\xi)=\int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{dx}{\big(\xi\tan(x)\big)^2+1} =\frac{\pi}{2(\xi+1)}.
$$
We now integrate our result wrt $\xi$ and realizing the constant of integration is zero, we obtain
$$
I(\xi)=\frac{\pi}{2}\ln(\xi+1).
$$
Taking the limit as $\xi \to 1$ we obtain
$$
\lim_{\xi \to 1} I(\xi)=\lim_{\xi \to 1} \frac{\pi}{2}\ln(\xi+1)=\frac{\pi \ln(2)}{2}.
$$
Thus we have shown that
$$
{\boxed{I=\frac{\pi\ln(2)}{2}}}
$$