# In the integral $\int_0^{\pi/2} x\cot x\,dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry, definite-integrals

$$\displaystyle\int_0^{\pi/2} x\cot x\,dx$$

By integration by parts I get a part $[x \ln|\sin x|]_0^{\pi/2}$ where $(\pi/2)\ln|\sin(\pi/2)|=0$ but, does $0\cdot \ln|\sin0|=0$ or is it indeterminate form of $0\cdot\infty$? Is there any way to find the above integral other than the integration by parts? I prefer if it is in elementary functions as I'm still a new student to Integration.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/692203/integral-int-0-pi-2-x-cotxdx-differntiation-wrt-parameter-only

Comment: $$\lim\limits_{x\to0}x\log\sin x=-\lim\limits_{x\to0}x^2\cot x=-\lim\limits_{x\to0}x\cos x=0$$Where I have used$$\lim\limits_{x\to0}\frac {x}{\sin x}=1$$

Answer (score 1):

Your integral is an *improper integral* because $\cot x$ is not continuous at $x=0$. To correct this issue, you should set up the problem as
$$
\int_0^{\pi/2}x\cot x\,dx=\lim_{a\to 0^+}\int_a^{\pi/2}x\cot x\,dx
$$
Then evaluate the integral
$$
\int_a^{\pi/2}x\cot x\,dx
$$
This will give you an expression in $a$. Once you have this expression take $a\to 0$.

Answer (score 0):

The function you have to integrate is not *defined* at $0$, but it is bounded on $(0,\frac{\pi}{2}]$, so this is a regular Riemann Integral, not an improper one. For $0<h<\frac{\pi}{2}$ the function is continuous on $[h,\frac{\pi}{2}]$, so you can apply the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, and then take the limit for $h\rightarrow 0^+$ of the function you get.