# Integral $\int_0^\infty \frac{\arctan(x) }{x(1+x^2)}\,dx$?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

How would one evaluate the integral $$\int_0^\infty \frac{\arctan(x) }{x(1+x^2)}\,dx$$?

I was told it had a nice closed form and could have been solved with differentiation under the integral sign; however, I tried to set $$I(\alpha) = \int_0^\infty \frac{\arctan(\alpha x)}{x(1+x^2)}~dx$$ and got nowhere (the resulting integral was very messy). Is there a much more clever substitution that can be used to tackle the integral?

Comment: Have you tried $\arctan x=t$?

Comment: For solving with differentiation under the integral sign see related https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/692203

Comment: use Fermat's trick @Teoc

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Rewrite

$$\frac{\arctan{x}}{x} = \int_0^1 \frac{du}{1+x^2 u^2} $$

Then plugging this in and reversing the order of integration, we get the integral; value as

$$\begin{align}\int_0^1 \frac{du}{u^2} \, \int_0^{\infty} dx \, \left (\frac1{\frac1{u^2}+x^2} \frac1{1+x^2} \right ) &= \int_0^1 \frac{du}{1-u^2} \, \int_0^{\infty} dx \left ( \frac1{1+x^2}-\frac1{\frac1{u^2}+x^2} \right )\\ &=  \int_0^1 \frac{du}{1-u^2} \, \frac{\pi}{2} (1-u) \\ &= \frac{\pi}{2} \log{2}\end{align}$$

Answer (score 8):

Let $x=\tan u$ then
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{\arctan(x) \,dx}{x(1+x^2)}=\int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{u}{\tan u}\ du =\int_0^{\pi/2} u\cot u\ du $$
now use 
[$$\int_0^{\pi/2} u\cot u \ du=\dfrac{\pi}{2}\ln2$$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/381976/tricky-elementary-integral)

Comment: How do you evaluate $I(a)$?  I think the integral diverges.

Comment: @Batominovski I dont think $I(a)$ give the final answer. it's better I use usually method. I'll correct that. thank you.

Answer (score 6):

Let $x=\tan(u)$, then
$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty\frac{\arctan(x)\,\mathrm{d}x}{x\left(1+x^2\right)}
&=\int_0^{\pi/2}u\cot(u)\,\mathrm{d}u\\
&=\int_0^{\pi/2}u\,\mathrm{d}\log(\sin(u))\\
&=-\int_0^{\pi/2}\log(\sin(u))\,\mathrm{d}u\\[6pt]
&=\frac\pi2\log(2)
\end{align}
$$
where the last step uses $(2)$ from [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/300319).

Answer (score 4):

Let

$$ I=\int_0^\infty \frac{\arctan(x) \,dx}{x(1+x^2)}.$$

The change of variable $\arctan x=t$ give us

$$I=\int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{t\cos t \,dt}{\sin t}=\frac{1}{2}\pi\log{2}$$

Comment: How do you obtain the last integral, though?

Answer (score 4):

A special case of [Ramanujan's master theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramanujan%27s_master_theorem) for integrating even functions over the positive reals was found by Glaisher in the late 19th century. If $f(x)$ is an even function with a series expansion around zero of the form:

$$f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n c_n x^{2n}$$

then

$$\int_0^{\infty}f(x) dx = \frac{\pi}{2}c_{-\frac{1}{2}}$$

if the integral converges. Here the rigorous definition of $c_{-\frac{1}{2}}$ follows from the rigorous statement of Ramanujan's master theorem, but in practice one can simply analytically continue the $c_k$ to fractional values of $k$ in a natural way, e.g. by replacing  factorials by gamma functions etc.

In this case, we have:

$$c_n = \sum_{k=0}^n\frac{1}{2k+1}\tag{1}$$

The natural way to analytically continue integer limits of summations to the reals or the complex plane is [given here](https://web.archive.org/web/20110617053801/http://www.math.tu-berlin.de/~mueller/HowToAdd.pdf). To evaluate $c_{-\frac{1}{2}}$ one can consider the large $n$ asymptotic expansion of $c_n$, treating $n$ as a continuous variable there allows one to shift lower limit of the summation to $\frac{1}{2}$, allowing one to extract the value of the summation from 0 to $-\frac{1}{2}$.

From the asymptotic formula:

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k} = \log(n) +\gamma +\mathcal{O}\left(n^{-1}\right)\tag{2}$$

we can derive the large $n$ asymptotics of $c_n$ by considering the summation over even $k$:

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{2k} = \frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k} =\frac{1}{2}\log(n) +\frac{1}{2}\gamma +\mathcal{O}\left(n^{-1}\right)\tag{3}$$

Using(2) and (3) we can then write:

$$c_n = \sum_{k=1}^{2n+2}\frac{1}{k} - \sum_{k=1}^{n+1}\frac{1}{2k} = \log(2) + \frac{1}{2}\log(n+1)+\frac{1}{2}\gamma +\mathcal{O}\left(n^{-1}\right)\tag{4}$$

Then the summation to $n$ in (1) can also be written as a summation to some arbitrary $u$ plus the summation from $u+1$ to $n$. This rule continues to hold for fractional summations whren $u$ and $n$ are arbitrary real or complex numbers. We thus have:

$$c_n = c_{-\frac{1}{2}} + \sum_{k=\frac{1}{2}}^n \frac{1}{2k+1}\tag{5}$$

We can write:

$$\sum_{k=\frac{1}{2}}^n \frac{1}{2k+1} = \sum_{k=1}^{n+\frac{1}{2}} \frac{1}{2k} = \frac{1}{2}\log\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right) +\frac{1}{2}\gamma +\mathcal{O}\left(n^{-1}\right)$$

Inserting this in (5) and using (4), we then find:

$$c_{-\frac{1}{2}} = \log(2) + \frac{1}{2}\log(n+1) - \frac{1}{2}\log\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right) + \mathcal{O}\left(n^{-1}\right)$$

Since there cannot be any dependence on $n$, the r.h.s. is actually a constant but this is not visible to us as we're not keeping track of any $\mathcal{O}\left(n^{-1}\right)$ terms. But taking the limit of $n\to\infty$ makes it clear that $c_{-\frac{1}{2}} = \log(2)$, therefore:

$$\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\arctan(x)dx}{x(1+x^2)}=\frac{\pi}{2}\log(2)$$

Answer (score 4):

The approach you were pointed to isn't that messy; we have $$I'=\int_0^\infty\frac{1}{1-\alpha^2}\bigg(\frac{1}{1+x^2}-\frac{\alpha^2}{1+\alpha^2 x^2}\bigg)dx=\frac{\pi/2}{1+\alpha},$$so from $I(0)=0$ we get $$I(\alpha)=\frac{\pi}{2}\ln|1+\alpha|,\,I(1)=\frac{\pi}{2}\ln 2.$$However, I think @RonGordon's [use](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2913905) of Feynman's trick is more interesting than this use of Feynman's trick.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
&\bbox[15px,#ffd]{\int_{0}^{\infty}{\arctan\pars{x} \over
x\pars{1 + x^{2}}}\,\dd x}
\,\,\,\stackrel{x\ =\ \tan\pars{\theta}}{=}\,\,\,
\int_{0}^{\pi/2}{\theta \over
\tan\pars{\theta}}\,\dd\theta
\\[5mm] = &\
\left.\Re\int_{\theta\ =\ 0}^{\theta\ =\ \pi/2}{-\ic\ln\pars{z} \over
-\ic\pars{z^{2} - 1}/\pars{z^{2} + 1}}\,{\dd z \over \ic z}
\,\right\vert_{\ z\ =\ \exp\pars{\ic\theta}}
\\[5mm] = &\
\left.-\,\Im\int_{\theta\ =\ 0}^{\theta\ =\ \pi/2}
{\pars{1 + z^{2}}\ln\pars{z} \over 1 - z^{2}}\,{\dd z \over z}
\,\right\vert_{\ z\ =\ \exp\pars{\ic\theta}}
\\[5mm] \stackrel{\mrm{as}\ \epsilon\ \to\ 0^{+}}{\sim}\,\,\, &\
\Im\int_{1}^{\epsilon}
{\pars{1 - y^{2}}\bracks{\ln\pars{y} + \ic\pi/2} \over 1 + y^{2}}
\,{\ic\,\dd y \over \ic y} +
\Im\int_{\pi/2}^{0}\bracks{\ln\pars{\epsilon} + \ic\theta}\,
{\epsilon\expo{\ic\theta}\ic\,\dd\theta \over \epsilon\expo{\ic\theta}}
\\[5mm] = &\
-\,{\pi \over 2}\int_{\epsilon}^{1}
{1 - y^{2} \over 1 + y^{2}}\,{\dd y \over y} -
{\pi \over 2}\ln\pars{\epsilon}
\\[5mm] = &\
-\,{\pi \over 2}\int_{\epsilon}^{1}
\pars{{1 - y^{2} \over 1 + y^{2}} - 1}\,{\dd y \over y} -
{\pi \over 2}\int_{\epsilon}^{1}{\dd y \over y} -
{\pi \over 2}\ln\pars{\epsilon}
\\[5mm] \stackrel{\mrm{as}\ \epsilon\ \to\ 0^{+}}{\to}\,\,\,&
\pi\int_{0}^{1}{y \over y^{2} + 1}\,\dd y =
\bbx{{1 \over 2}\,\pi\ln\pars{2}}
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

Note
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{\arctan(x) }{x(1+x^2)}\,dx=\frac12\int_0^\infty \frac1x d\arctan^2(x)=\frac12\int_0^\infty \frac{\arctan^2(x)}{x^2} \,dx.$$
Now define
$$ I(a,b)=\int_0^\infty \frac{\arctan(ax)\arctan(bx)}{x^2} \,dx $$
and then
\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{\partial^2I(a,b)}{\partial a\partial b}&=&\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{(1+a^2x^2)(1+b^2x^2)} \,dx\\
&=&\frac{1}{a^2-b^2}\int_0^\infty\bigg(\frac{a^2}{1+a^2x^2}-\frac{b^2}{1+b^2x^2}\bigg)\;dx\\
&=&\frac{\pi}{2(a+b)}.
\end{eqnarray}
So
$$ \int_0^\infty \frac{\arctan(x) }{x(1+x^2)}\,dx=\frac12\int_0^\infty \frac{\arctan^2(x)}{x^2} \,dx=\frac\pi4\int_0^1\int_0^1\frac{1}{a+b}=\frac{\pi}{2}\ln2. $$